# My code picks last row of sheet instead of last data row in sheet? My rows dont have any hidden formulas

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a appscript code using "getlastrow" but it gets last row of the sheet instead of last row of data whereas my rows below data are completely empty and dont even have any hidden formulas.

How can i get last row with data instead of last row of sheet